# What would be the proper way of handling arguments for a method that could be ints or chars in python?

Tags: python, arguments

For example, I want to have a method that, depending on the first argument passed, can take either an int or a char as the second argument.

The way I thought of doing it is to have an if right after the method it calls to check what the first argument is, it can be one of 4. At this point, if it's of say, type 1 or 2 that expects an int as the second argument, it completes the code within the if. I then have an elif checking if the first argument is of type 3 or 4, then it goes into that block and completes the code within that block. The else will throw an exception or handle the issue accordingly.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes. "Simple is better than complicated"

Comment: It might be helpful to get a little more context so we can understand why your code is designed this way.

Comment: It's how the project is required to work by the professor.

Comment: If your professor is teaching you to branch code based on the type of an argument, beware: you're learning a language from someone who doesn't even grasp the basic principles of that language.  Also, there's no such thing as a "char" in Python.

Comment: I would recommend deciding what the most common type of input would be and writing the code to handle that type, but put in exception handlers if the input is something else.

Comment: Glenn how do you suggest I handle it? I know there aren't chars, I just wanted to indicate it's single letters, not strings. He also admits he's not the greatest programmer, he's a theory guy

Comment: Ok and maybe I wasn't specific enough. The arguments will provide a range. The range is the second argument. The first indicates what range in the data structure to use. It then returns a list of items in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better have two different methods if inner code is different in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is same, with some transformation of parameteres (getting ASCII value of char for example - btw, char in python is just a string with length of 1), you should do the cast at the start of function and the rest of the code should be the same. For example:

```
def foo(a, b):
    if a == 1:
        b = ord(b)
    # use b as if it is integer
```

If the rest of the code is totaly different you sholud be writing different functions and not trying to squeeze it in one.